# Duplication localStorage data using backbone.js + backbone.localStorage.js

Tags: backbone.js, local-storage

I'm using backbone + backbone.localStorage to persist my data, and I get a wrong behavior:

I've got a model settings with one attribute called user

```js
Settings = Backbone.Model.extend({
    localStorage : new Backbone.LocalStorage('settingsStore')
});
var settings = new Settings();
settings.set({user: 'USERNAME'});
settings.save();
```

After this code if I output the settings.attributes data in weinre I get the following:

```js
  settings.attributes  
   Object  
   id: "3ac78cfb-ad60-1ab8-8391-f058ae9bfcfb"  
   user: "USERNAME"  
   __proto__: Object
```

Then I save the model to the localStorage, clear, and fetch it again:

```
settings.save();
settings.clear();
settings.fetch();
```

And the problem is that if I output the settings.attributes, now this attributes are stored inside a nested object:

```js
   settings.attributes  
   Object  
   0: Object  
       id: "3ac78cfb-ad60-1ab8-8391-f058ae9bfcfb"  
       user: "USERNAME"  
       __proto__: Object  
   __proto__: Object
```

And the problem is when I set the user name again in order to modify, a new attribute is added like this:

```js
   settings.attributes  
   Object  
   0: Object  
   id: "3ac78cfb-ad60-1ab8-8391-f058ae9bfcfb"  
   user: "USERNAME"  
   __proto__: Object  
   user: "NEWUSER"  
   __proto__: Object
```

And if I save this model, and fetch it again I get 2 new objects on the attributes... and it keeps growing each time.

Comment: Looks like the problem is that `Backbone.localStorage` [is meant to work with Collections and it doesn't work properly with Models](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544503/backbone-js-saving-one-model-in-local-storage).

Comment: Mmmm... It's strange because in the tests folder of backbone.localstorage github they show an example to use it with a Model (book)... https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage/blob/master/tests/test.js

Comment: I'm playing with [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fguillen/CPuYH) and I see a very weird behavior in the last `console.log` instead of seeing a hash of attributes I see an array of attributes of all Models saved in the past. Try to execute the code several times. Also [beware with loggin Objects in the JS console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9911637/backbone-js-model-get-returning-undefined-even-though-i-can-see-the-attribut/9912865#9912865)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the question given by fguillen link gives the correct answer to this problem.

You just need to create the model object with a hardcoded "ID" if you want to save it correctly.

After doing this:

```js
var settings = new Settings({ id: 1 });
```

The save() and fecth() methods are working correctly. Obviously you have to take care not repeating 2 ID's...