# Fetching a model using Backbone.LocalStorage returns success even though item does not exist

Tags: backbone.js, local-storage, backbone-local-storage

If I haven't saved my Backbone Model to local storage ([via Backbone.LocalStorage adapter](http://documentup.com/jeromegn/backbone.localStorage)) using the save() method, how come fetch() returns a success callback? Shouldn't it return an error or some other indication that the model is not in fact in local storage?

My model:

```
 var User = Backbone.Model.extend({

    initialize: function(){
    },

    localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage("User"),

    defaults: { 
        HANDLE: '',
        EMAIL: '',
        UUID: '',
        USERPIC: '',
        TOKENLOGIN: '',
        SIGNUPSTATUS: ''
    },
});

app.User = new User();
```

And later, when I fetch it:

```
app.User.fetch({success:this.userFetchSuccess, error:this.userFetchError});
```

The callback I get every time is the success callback. Can't imagine why!

**Update**: Looks like the localStorage adapter may not work properly with Models. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544503/backbone-js-saving-one-model-in-local-storage) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10549056/duplication-localstorage-data-using-backbone-js-backbone-localstorage-js).

Comment: Another Update: If I follow the instructions here... https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage/issues/56 ... the adapter uses the error callback instead! Perfect. Have spent quite a bit of time on this - hopefully it saves somebody else some agony.